# Repeatable way to generate an anonymous identifier?

Tags: identity, privacy, anonymous-users

I've been working on a web application that needs to provide a way to create an **anonymous identifier** that can be used to identify one or more rows in a database that refer to a person who has called into a switchboard (let's call them a "**client**") *without actually storing any identifiable information* about that **client**. The **switchboard operator** should be able to:

1. ask a few questions of the **client** that (*ideally*) only the client can answer
2. enter their responses into an ephemeral online "calculator" form that *doesn't save/submit the data*
3. receive an **anonymous identifier** from that form
4. enter that **anonymous identifier** into the the app that will be used to handle the **client**'s request (let's call that the **CRM**)

Notably:

- *personally identifiable information* must *never* be stored in the **CRM**
- the same questions are asked of every **client**
- if the same **client** calls again one year later—and *answers the same questions*—a different **switchboard operator** would get the same **anonymous identifier** in response, and would see the entries about that **client** entered into the **CRM** by other operators into the who have answered calls from that same **client** in the past
- the **client** is ***never asked to remember an identifier, password, or other secret***

For example, John Doe calls the switchboard, and is asked to provide their:

- First and Last name
- DOB
- City of birth

In my prototype: the name is processed with a simple *Soundex*-like algorithm (to avoid spelling errors) and returns a number; the date of birth returns a number a the number of days since an arbitrary epoch; and the city of birth returns a *Where on Earth Identifier*. These are then concatenated, salted, and hashed to return an anonymous identifier (e.g. `3:L3kmw:Ly`, using SSDEEP so that the **switchboard operator** doesn't have to type many characters into the **CRM**), though the hashing algorithm isn't important). The form used to generate the **anonymous identifier** calculates everything in the browser, and doesn't store/save/submit anything.

Is there a better approach to *reproducibly* generate an **anonymous identifier**? Are there better questions/procedures to reduce the risk of social engineering by others who might wish to gain information about a **client**?

Interested in all ideas, critiques, etc.. Will edit with changes as requested.

Comment: Good question. I'd be concerned about the low entropy the questions create; I think you might get better answers on https://security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks; also posted there.